# String fragment needs to replace by '<'

Tags: java, string

Hi could anyone please help me for replacing string "<" by "<"
from below string. Here I don't want to replace.

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("</I></B>250-500 mg 6 hrly.<BR><B><I>Child: </I></B><I><7 days</I></B> and <2 kg: 25 mg/kg 12 hrly; "
  + "<I>7-28 days</B> and <2 kg or <I>&le;7 days</I> and &ge;2 kg: 25 mg/kg 8 hrly; <I>7-28 days</I> and &ge;2 kg: 25 mg/kg 6 hrly; <I>&ge;1 mth</I> and <20 kg: 50-100 mg/kg daily 6 hrly. Max: 4 g daily. For severe infection, up to 200 mg/kg daily in divided doses. "
  + "Max: 12 g daily.<BR><I>Parenteral</I><BR><B>Staphylococcal infections resistant to benzylpenicillin</I><BR><Bold><I>Adult: "
  + "</I></I>1-2 g 6 hrly. For more severe infections (e.g. meningitis, endocarditis), 2 g 4 hrly.<BR><Bold><I>Child: "
  + "</I></I><I><7 days</I></I> and <2 kg: 25 mg/kg 12 hrly; <I>7-28 days</I> and <2 kg or <I>&le;7 days</I> and &ge;2 kg: 25 mg/kg 8 hrly; "
  + "<I>7-28 days</I> and &ge;2 kg: 25 mg/kg 6 hrly; <I>&ge;1 mth</I> and <20 kg: 50-100 mg/kg daily 6 hrly. "
  + "Max: 4 g daily. For severe infection, up to 200 mg/kg daily in divided doses. Max: 12 g daily.");
```

Need to consider some cases here, if < followed by immediate number only then only < needs to be replaced with &lt: otherwise no change. I have tried below method but it replacing number also.

```
s.replaceAll("<[0-9]","&lt;");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the number or it will be lost in the replace.

You want something like this.

```
s.replaceAll("<([0-9]+)","&lt;$1");
```